# Changing a variable in node.js callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to change the value of a variable in the callback function.

```
db.collection("some_collection").find().toArray(function(err, arrayResult){
  var myArrayResult = arrayResult;

  some_asynchronous_call(param1, param2, successCallback, failureCallback);

  function successCallback() {
     myArrayResult.reverse();
     processResults();
  }

  function failurCallback() {
     processResults();   
  }

  function processResults(){
     //Do some processing on myArrayResult array 
  }

}
```

So basically I need access to the variable `myArrayResult` in both successCallback and failureCallback functions. If the asynchronous calls is successful then I need to reverse the array. However in both the cases the processResults needs to run on the array.

Comment: You should have access to it.

Comment: Yeah, are you saying this _doesn't_ work?  You could even pull the definition of `myArrayResult` out to a higher level function scope, as long as the `successCallback`, `failureCallback`, and `processResults` function are defined within this function scope.

Comment: Note that if you start needing access to more than 1 or 2 variables, it might be cleaner to put them all into a context object, say, a `whatImDoingContext = { arrayResult: arrayResult, foo: foo }`

Comment: This is probably just an oversight on your post, but make sure you declare processResults() as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy since `successCallback`, `failureCallback`, `processResults` are clousre functions the array `myArrayResult` should be available in those functions.

You can do like this to make the array `myArrayResult` available to successCallback and failureCallback.

```
db.collection("some_collection").find().toArray(function(err, arrayResult){
  var myArrayResult = arrayResult;

  some_asynchronous_call(param1, param2, function(){successCallback(myArrayResult)}, function(){failureCallback(myArrayResult)});

  function successCallback(arraydata) {
     arraydata.reverse();
     processResults(arraydata);
  }

  function failurCallback(arraydata) {
     processResults(arraydata);   
  }

  processResults(arraydata){
     // do processing on arraydata
     res.end(JSON.stringify({data: arraydata}));
  }

}
```